# How to Join on Django Using ORM

Tags: python, django

Hello everybody I am at my wits' end here, I need help with doing a simple join between 2 tables using DJANGO ORM.

The ultimate goal is to return a json response compatible with datatable which contains the product details and product category name instead of the category id.

**Like this**

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 1,
    "recordsFiltered": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "productid": 4,
            "sku": "000001",
            "shortcode": "CBG",
            "category": 2,
            "categoryname": "Burgers",
            "productname": "Cheese Burger",
            "description": "This is a cheese burger",
            "barcode": "000001",
            "treshhold": 10,
            "isactive": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here are my models**

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    categoryid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    categoryname = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    isactive= models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table="tblProductCategory"
        

class Product(models.Model):
    productid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,default=0)
    productname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    treshhold = models.IntegerField()
    isactive= models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table="tblProduct"
```

**Here is my view**

```
def get_product(request):
    recordsTotal = 0
    draw = int(request.GET['draw'])
    start = int(request.GET['start'])
    length = int(request.GET['length'])

    products = Product.objects.filter(sku__icontains = request.GET['sku']).select_related('category')
    
    recordsTotal = products.count()
    recordsFiltered = recordsTotal

    page =  start / length + 1

    paginator = Paginator(products, length)

    try:
        object_list = paginator.page(page).object_list
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        object_list = paginator.page(draw).object_list
    except EmptyPage:
        object_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages).object_list

    data = [model_to_dict(product) for product in object_list]

    json_res={
        "draw": draw,
        "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered": recordsFiltered,
        'data':data,
    }

    return JsonResponse(json_res);
```

**My serializer**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model =Product
            fields = '__all__'
```

Using Serializers seems to be the way to go. But I seriously don't understand how they work or how to implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source="category.categoryname")

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'productid',
            'sku',
            'shortcode',
            'category',
            'productname',
            'description',
            'barcode',
            'treshhold',
            'isactive'
       ]
```

In view like that:

```
try:
    object_list = paginator.page(page).object_list
except PageNotAnInteger:
    object_list = paginator.page(draw).object_list
except EmptyPage:
    object_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages).object_list
serializer = ProductSerializer(object_list, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the category name at `products[index].category.categoryname`.

Comment: okay. but can you tell how to add category name to my data?

Comment: It is already in your data. Using `select_related` allows you to pre-populate the foreign key field. If what you want to do is "flatten" the category data with the products data, you can either build a serializer for products or if you wanna continue doing what you are doing you can manually flatten the products while converting them into a dict.

Comment: yes. im sorry but I really don't know how to use serializer. I a already built one but I dont know how to continue. Ill update my question to include my Serializer

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting data of category table i.e. Ctaegory name
You can try to fetch them one by one

For example :

```
products = Product.objects.filter(sku__icontains=request.GET['sku']).values(
    'productid', 'sku', 'shortcode', 'category_id', 'category__categoryname',
    'productname', 'description', 'barcode', 'treshhold', 'isactive'
)
```